# Activerecord rescue

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have a ruby app that uses `ActiveRecord` but not `Rails`.

I want to rescue from all database errors which in my case can include a `SQLite3::BusyException`.

Is there a better way than to wrap every `Model.find`, `Model.where`, `obj.save`, etc in a rescue?

I thought adding a module to every model that monkey patches/hijacks DB actions such as, but `where` appears complex and something not to be trifled with:

```
def where
  super
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
rescue SQLite3::BusyException => e
  p [:warning, e.message]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

When using Celluloid I ran into a similar issue where I needed to trap errors due to the connection pooling not working correctly with how Celluloid was using fibers. I used something like the following wrapper method to help make sure errors were trapped and resolved the connection reaping in my code. For your scenario, it could look like this:

```rb
module TrackActiveRecordErrors
  def db(&block)
    begin
      yield block
    rescue StandardError => e
      p [:warning, e.message]
      # ... and other sort of logging, alerting you'd like
      raise e
    ensure
      # Put your clean-up code here
    end
  end
end
```

In classes you want to use this wrapper:

```
class DoSomething
  include TrackActiveRecordErrors

  def find_something(id)
    db do
      a_something = Model.find(id)
    end
    a_something
  end
end
```

It's not pretty, but it's a lot easier than trying to tune AR's magic in the model classes.

Comment: Thanks, but this is quite similar to monkey patching the functions directly. It carries the similar "gotchas".